# INSERT null into nullable datetime field causes operand clash

Tags: sql-server, vb6, adodb

i'm trying to insert a record into a table. all fields are nullable. 
for the field that has a nullable datetime, i want the value NULL but i get the runtime error

```
"Operand type clash: text is incompatible with datetime"
```

can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;"
Call conn.Open

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (StartDate,Place) VALUES (?,?)"
Call cmd.Execute(, Array(Null, "Home"))
```

***EDIT: table definition***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Place] [char](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Can you add how the CREATE TABLE statement for that table  looks?

Comment: @Gnudiff added the CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: Try providing valid Options flags instead of letting them default to "unspecified."

Comment: @Bob77 if you mean something `Call cmd.Execute(, Array(Null, "Home"), adExecuteNoRecords)`, i just tried it and it gives the same error. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing the parameters as part of the `Execute` method, you should use [`CreateParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado). This allows you to specify the type of each parameter to ensure that it matches the type of the column in the database.

(Don't forget to also add the parameter to the `Parameters` collection - a common mistake is to assume `CreateParameter` will do that for you).

The problem with passing your parameters as part of the `Execute` method is that you force ADO to *deduce* the parameter types. And `Null` isn't easy to deduce type information from (since its a valid "value" for multiple types)

Comment: but Null has it's own type in VB6 and i would imagine that it giving the SQL value null to a field is the same in SQL no matter what the type of the destination field is. also, "Execute" distinquishes Null just fine for the other parameter. i was hoping reuse the Command object and avoid the verbose CreateParameter syntax

Comment: @symbiont it is not necessarily dependent on vb6 datatype. It could well be that simple vb6 Null gets converted into eg '' by ADODB. You should examine sql server log for the actual query that gets passed to it.

Comment: nice tip. it seems to actually get converted to NULL so something else is going wrong. it results in: exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO MyTable (StartDate,Place) VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 text,@P2 char(4)',NULL,'home'

Comment: @symbiont it looks like adodb uses the null you provided, but assumes parameter type to be text instead of datetime. An attempt to use text type for value is producing error despite the actual "text" value being null. You are well advised to follow the advice given in this answer and use Parameters.

Comment: this seems to work best. i ended up using CreateParameter with a helper function. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
Call cmd.Execute(, Array(Null, "Home"))
```

to this

```
Call cmd.Execute(DBNull.Value, Array(Null, "Home"))
```

Comment: where can i find DBNull.Value? i'm using VB6

Comment: check this documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh - this is VB6/ADO classic - *not* .NET.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh it doesn't look like that could work but i tried it anyway. Call db.Execute(, (Null, "home")) is a syntax error and Call db.Execute(Null, "home") gives the run-time error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Answer (score 0):

this proved to not always work so i went with Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (StartDate,Place) VALUES (CAST(? AS NVARCHAR),?)"
Call cmd.Execute(, Array(Null, "Home"))
```